# Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, webforms

I have in my SQL database column `aeStart` as `time(0)` (which save time in 24 hour format), for example: `10:48:00`, `15:28:00`, `16:32:00`

I am trying to display it on `listView` control in format `hh:mm tt` (am/pm format)

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStart" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("aeStart")).ToShortTimeString() %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

If I try:

```
Text='<%# Eval("aeStart", "{0:HH:mm tt}") %>'
```

I get:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

If I just do:

```
Text='<%# Eval("aeStart") %>'
```

I'll get something like

> 10:48:00 or 15:25:00

which not what I want.

> I want 10:48 am or 3:25 pm

How to fix this, I want the time is displayed on that label in 12-hour format with am/pm (prefer all the code on the .aspx file, not in code behind)

### ANSWER:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStart" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("aeStart").ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortTimeString() %>' />
```

Comment: What data type and format is the datetime stored in the db?

Comment: @Mathemats, `time(0)` as said in the question.

Comment: So why not use `DateTime`? That's not a timespan you have there.

Comment: What is the value of `aeStart` at that time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is: your time `10:48:00` doesn't match the pattern `HH:mm tt`. You should use this pattern instead: `HH:mm:ss`.

I tested it with this code:

```
    string time = "10:48:00";
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToShortTimeString());
```

So, in your situation, the solution should be:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStart" runat="server" Text="<%# DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("aeStart").ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortTimeString() %>"/>
```

Comment: How to do this on the `.aspx`, I don't want to use this on code behind since it will involving `Findcontrol` on `Listview rowDatabound` and stuffs

Comment: How about changing `Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("aeStart")).ToShortTimeString()` into `DateTime.ParseExact("aeStart", "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortTimeString()`?

Comment: I got `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: Could you debug and see what is the value of string "aeStart" at that time?

Comment: basically I got an exception, I don't know how to see the value, what variable I have to add on watch list, I added the `lblStart` Label but nothing

Comment: Can you just display that value to the screen without touching it? Try to put it in a label.

Comment: It will display exactly as in database, such as `10:48:00` or `15:25:00`, see my updated question

Comment: OK, so try this: `DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("aeStart"), "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortTimeString();`

Comment: Awesome! thanks, you should update the answer for `.aspx` code as well with a little bit of modifications, here is code that worked: `DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("aeStart").ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: I forgot the `Eval()` function in my first comment, which leads to a stupid exception, LOL :P Anyway, it's good to see the problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload of `Convert.ToDateTime` that excepts a `TimeSpan`. Read up about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

The way to fix this is to do something entirely different, because the method has no overload to do this. Here is how you could get just the time in another way:

```
TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(your time span value);
DateTime time = DateTime.Today.Add(timespan);
string displayTime = time.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: This should be a comment as the OP's question is `How to fix` not why.

Comment: The way to fix is to not try to cast a TimeSpan to a DateTime, so how is this answer wrong? You can't solve this, you can do something else entirely.

Comment: I'm not saying it was wrong, I just said it did not answer the question. Also, I did not downvote your answer. Here is a +1 to prove that!

Comment: Sorry Felix, I just hate when guys do that, when each of us are on here just to help and get helped and I was basically just trying to let this guy know that he was going about it wrong, but there were other alternatives.

Comment: I understand. I just posted that comment since I predict downvotes and flags coming even if your answer is *basically* correct, just that it does not directly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TimeSpan.ToSting(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
timeSpan.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
```

The idea of AM/PM doesn't really make sense for a timespan in the general sense.  Whether that timespan took place in the am, pm, or was split between them is metadata specific to the context of your application.  You could add an additional string.Format or similar with ternary logic to determine what part of the day the timespan pertains to.

Comment: not good since I just Eval it directly and it will display 24-hour format, I want 12-hour format with am/pm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `aeStart` is a `TimeSpan`, then the format string with "tt" is wrong. 'tt', the AM/PM designator, is valid for a `DateTime` **NOT** a `TimeSpan`.